# How to store the error/residue of mpmath.findroot for a particular input guess?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, mpmath

We have a specific set of equations whose solutions are highly dependent on the input guesses. If we use verbose given [in the docs](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html) it displays a whole lot of extra information. We only want the error, or to be precise the RESIDUE. How do we obtain that obtain that?

For instance, consider the following code snippet:

```
import mpmath as mp
def f(x):
  return [#some function of x]
y = mp.findroot(f, x0 = [1 + 1j])
print(y)
```

If we run the code, we get the following **error:
Could not find root within given tolerance. (0.037331322115722662107 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments.** (the actual code has many more variables unlike the above code)

Now, we can silence this warning by setting the argument verify = False, as given [in the docs](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html).

In which case, we do get the output value, but this is not the exact output, and it has some error/residue associated with it.

Now, if we were to set up a loop and input a whole variety of starting guesses x0's, one can get as the output an arrays of corresponding y's. however, can we also get the error/residue committed in the mp.findroot solver corresponding to each y?

For instance, it would be nice if there was something like

```
z = mp.findroot.error(f, x0)
```

Thus for each guess x0, we could get a corresponding y and a corresponding z, and this would allow us to pick from all the initial guesses, which is the best one(i.e the one which produces the smallest residue)

Is there any way of finding the explicit value of this residue, and storing it in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to do it in python, but instead if you want the same you can try to do this in Matlab using function handles.

```
fun = @(x) exp(-exp(-x)) - x; % function
x0 = [0 1]; % initial interval
options = optimset('Display','final'); % show final answer
[x fval exitflag output] = fzero(fun,x0,options)
```

Here x will be value and fval will be the error in the value.